# What are the advantages of using different anaconda enviroments for different projects?

Tags: python, anaconda, environment

I just want to ask...maybe a very stupid question but I want to be sure...
What are the advantages of using different anaconda enviroments for different projects?
Also, why would it be bad to have just one with all the packages installed?

Answer (score 0):

Advantages using environments per project are e.g.:

- Be able to use different versions of the same packages in different projects.
- Ensure only using dependencies you are aware of in your projects, so you are able to reproduce the environment for specific projects on other machines.

Hence some disadvantages when not using environments per project:

- If you want to update a package that requires updates in your code, you would need to update all projects which use that package.
- You could forget adding dependencies to your project's environment file, because it is in the global environment anyways and therefore nobody forced you to do so.

See the [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) and [Conda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/concepts/environments.html) docs about environments for further information.